# Checking my reasoning for a Bayesian inference problem using the binomial distribution (lottery combinations)

Tags: probability, bayesian, binomial-distribution

I’m new to Bayesian statistics (self-studying), R and StackExchange. This forum has been extremely helpful for finding flaws in my reasoning. Is it all right if I ask for help in checking my logic for the question below? Are there any more explanations I should add? My solution matches one of the possible solutions, but I want to know whether my logic is correct and if I am explaining the steps in sufficient detail.

***Question:***

> You decide to conduct a statistical analysis of a lottery to determine
>   how many possible lottery combinations there were. If there are N
>   possible lottery combinations, each person has a 1/N chance of
>   winning. Suppose that 413,271,201 people played the lottery and three
>   people won. You are told that the number of lottery combinations is a
>   multiple of 100 million and less than 1 billion, but have no other
>   prior information to go on. What is the posterior probability that
>   there were fewer than 600 million lottery combinations?

***My Solution:***

**Posterior**

= P(Fewer than 600 million lottery combinations | 3 winners out of 413271201 players)

**Prior (uniform)**
= 1/9

There are nine possible outcomes for N. We are counting in increments of 100 million, from 100 million to 900 million. Hence the Prior = 1/9

To find the Likelihood and Data, I use the dbinom function in R to calculate the probability of k successes for a binomial variable, given that the probability of success = 1/N.

**Likelihood**

= P(3 winners out of 413271201 players | Fewer than 600 million lottery combinations)

```
= dbinom(3,413271201,1/100000000) +  
dbinom(3,413271201,1/200000000) +  
dbinom(3,413271201,1/300000000) +  
dbinom(3,413271201,1/400000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/500000000)
= 0.5913931
```

**Data**

```
= 1/9 {
dbinom(3,413271201,1/100000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/200000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/300000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/400000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/500000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/600000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/700000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/800000000) + 
dbinom(3,413271201,1/900000000)
}
= 0.07351668
```

Hence, **Posterior**

```
= (Prior * Likelihood) / Data
= (1/9 * 0.5913931) / 0.07351668
= 0.894
```

Comment: I know this is the correct answer after cross-checking with someone else. This thread can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I argue because the number of players was 413,271,201, We are counting in increments of 100 million, from **500 million** to 900 million, not 100 million. Which means that the number of models would be 5. However, I do wonder whether the key distinction is the *no other prior information to go on*, which would include not knowing how many people participated in the lottery?